# How calculate gdax 24 hours percentage

Tags: gdax-api

How can I fetch the GDAX 24 hours percentage for each products?

Should I request current price and current-24hours price and process the difference ? Or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it...

```
$stats = fetchFromGDAX("/products/$product-USD/stats");
$x = round((($stats['last']-$stats['open'])/$stats['open'])*100,3);
```

( `fetchFromGDAX()` is my function to handle the API call )

This returns something like... `-3.394%`